# How can I query embedded records in a Djongo ArrayField?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-queryset, djongo

I'm using Django 3.0.6 with Django Rest Framework 3.11.1. I'm connecting to a MongoDB database using the [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) connector. One of my models has an ArrayField that contains embedded records. I would like to know how I can retrieve these embedded fields using a django query.

Each Person can have many different sub records. Here is a sample model to illustrate what I'm working on

Models:

```py
from djongo import models

class SubRecords(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    startTime = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    workplace = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    records = models.ArrayField(model_container=SubRecords)
```

I would like to query the `Person` model and get

1. all `Person.records` objects and
2. `Person.records` objects that match some criteria

I have tried to do this

```
>>> Person.objects.filter(records__exact={'job_title': 'HR'})
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that the result isn't limited to subrecords where the job title is HR, instead if a `Person` object contains a sub record that matches the criteria, the whole Person object and associated sub records are returned.
I want to be able to get a list of all the subrecords and only the subrecords that match the criteria I specify. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need __exact:

```
Person.objects.filter(records={'job_title':'HR'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it like this

```
Person.objects.filter(records__in={'job_title':'HR'})
```

You can add `.all()` at the end of query if you want.